# @ngx-translate get observable not firing on language change

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

Using angular2 with @ngx-translate module

I code which does a language change based on user selection and set the language using:

```
this.translate.use('en');
```

Elsewhere in other components I am using the .get observable to retrieve some labels.

```
this.translate.get(element.bucketId.toUpperCase()).subscribe( x => { bucket.bucketLabel = x; } );
```

The initial label of the current language loads fine, but when the .use is executed, the label does not change to the new language.  The observable does not fire.

To get around this I have to do the following:

```
this.translate.get(element.bucketId.toUpperCase()).subscribe( x => { bucket.bucketLabel = x; } );
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe( event => {
    bucket.bucketLabel = this.translate.instant(element.bucketId.toUpperCase());
});
```

This obviously seems excessive.

Code using the pipes and directives switch languages perfectly.

Am I misinterpreting what the .get does? Or is there some other trick I am missing when doing the language switch.  Something beyond just doing a this.translate.use(lang);

Answer (score 9):

Try the `.stream()` method, it will return new values when the language changes.

https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#methods

Comment: this.translate.stream('DASHBOARD.LOGOUT');  comes up with:Property 'stream' does not exist on type 'TranslateService'

Comment: saved much time...thumbs up